Why does acpi_listen detect an event but acpid does not?
I have an weird disconnect between acpi_listen and journalctl -u acpid: When I run the former and close, then open my laptops lid, I get the following output:
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open

However, the acpid log shows absolutely no activity.
This is an issue for be because I am trying to run a script when the lid is closed / opened. To this end I created the file /etc/acpi/events/lidconf with the content
# run a script on lid open/close events
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/actions/lid.sh

The file under /etc/acpi/actions/lid.sh is executable contains the following:
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /home/<my-user>/LidEvent

This is obviously just a test script, but it does exactly what I expect it to when running it manually. Unfortunately it is not triggered by acpid, even though acpi-Events for opening / closing clearly exist. What could be going wrong here?
My system:

Operating System: Bazzite 41
KDE Plasma Version: 6.2.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.8.0
Qt Version: 6.8.0
Kernel Version: 6.11.10-304.bazzite.fc41.x86_64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 8840U w/ Radeon 780M Graphics
Memory: 46.8 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Graphics
Manufacturer: GPD
Product Name: G1619-04
System Version: Ver.1.0

